# Windows Phone 8.1 Store Map

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I want to use **Bing** Map into my Windows **Phone** 8.1 store app. I know the WP8.1 SDK's **MapControl** API, which is used for map.

Is that a *Bing* map or *Nokia* map or *HERE* map, any official document about that?

If it is Nokia Map and not Bing Map, How to use Bing maps.

There is [Windows 8.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1) SDK available, and not for Windows Phone 8.1.

Any workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in maps in WP 7/8/8.1 is a Bing Maps control that is built into the WP SDK. This is also the case for WP10/Win10. Google maps has no map controls for Windows Phone.

You should target WP8.1 and not WP8 as that's the version most WP users are on. The WP8.1 maps control is also more inline with the WP10/Win10 map controls, so it will make it easier for you to upgrade your app in the future. You can find documentation here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx

Comment: I am targetting to WP 8.1 only as mentioned in question. Where its written that WP8.1 maps are bing maps as if we use MapControl no bing copywrite comes.

Comment: Beacause in WP8 maps if we use Phone.Controls.Maps then it shows map with bing logo info. Its not the case with WP8.1 MapControl. I want to make sure I am using bing map on WP 8.1

Comment: The map control in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace is a Microsoft map control (i.e. Bing Maps). Since it's built into the Windows Phone SDK, the logo/copyright information may not need to be shown. The map control is set to show this info if needed.